# Generalized eigen property of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, eigenvalues, determinants

Given a $n \times n$ invertible matrix $A$, I am interested in the set

$$
\mathcal{S}(A) = \{ D \textrm{ diagonal matrix } \mid \det(D - A) = 0 \}.
$$

Thus, for all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, we have $\lambda_i I \in \mathcal{S}(A)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I would like to learn more about this set $\mathcal{S}(A)$. Is there a name for it in literature? In particular, I am interested whether it can be parametrized in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. Further, I am interested in unitary $U$ and $ \mathcal{S}_\textrm{1} \subset \mathcal{S}(U)$ such that for $D \in \mathcal{S}_\textrm{1}$ that $$|d_{11}| = \dots = |d_{nn}| = 1$$

Comment: inspection of $n=2$, for a symmetric $A$, will tell you that you need the eigenvectors as well as the eigenvalues of $A$ to parameterize the two  diagonal elements of $D$ that satisfy ${\rm det}\,(D-A)=0$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Right, I included the eigenvectors to the question.

Comment: If $A$ is upper triangular then this set consists of all diagonal matrices which share at least one diagonal entry with $A$ (same value in the same position).

Comment: @NikWeaver I see this, but how can you generalize from this fact to non-triangular matrices?

Comment: Requiring $A$ to be unitary doesn't restrict $D$ to be unitary. Take, for example, $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0.8 & 0.6 \\ -0.6 & 0.8 \end{array} \right]$; then $S_A = \{(d_{11}, d_{22})|(d_{11} - 0.8)(d_{22} - 0.8) + 0.36 = 0\}$.

Comment: @user44191 yes you're right. I have corrected the question. I restricted it to explicitly ask for the unitary subset.

Comment: There's an obvious part to the answer: the set $D$ will be an affine variety of codimension $1$, given as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^n$ with an equation where each $x_i$ appears with degree $1$ and with a coefficient of $1$ for $\prod_{i = 1}^n x_i$. I think unitarity should only give that the constant coefficient is $1$, but haven't checked.

Comment: @user44191 With $D$, you mean $\mathcal{S}(A)$? Also the unitarity adds a palindromic property to the coefficients (and for this the constant coefficient is 1).